# Why is for-in slower than while in swift debugging mode?

Tags: swift, for-loop

Why is for-in slower than while  in swift debugging mode ?
If you think, yes It was ran in **no optimization**.

⬇️Below code, Time is compare of for-in and while in no optimization

49999995000000
for-in  -- time = 3.3352

4999999950000000
while  -- time = 0.3613

⬇️but, If using **optimization for speed**

49999995000000
for-in  -- time = 0.0037

49999995000000
while  -- time = 0.0035

I wonder that "why is for-in slower than while in no optimization?  and why are for-in and while so fast in optimization? "

```swift
import Foundation

func processTime(_ title: String, blockFunction: () -> ()) {
    print()
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    blockFunction()
    let processTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print(title, " -- time = \(String(format : "%.4f",processTime))")
}

processTime("for-in") {
    var sum = 0
    for i in 0..<10000000 {
        sum += i
    }
    print(sum)
}

processTime("while") {
    var sum = 0
    var i = 0
    while i<10000000 {
        sum += i
        i += 1
    }
    print(sum)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a Swift perspective, your `for` loop actually translates to something like this:

```
let range = 0..<10000000
var iterator = range.makeIterator()
while let next = iterator.next() {
    ...
}
```

Notice that's a lot of calls to `next` on the range's iterator, which has its own state that has to be kept track of, and `IndexingIterator.next` calls a bunch of protocol methods, dispatching which takes some time too as it has to lookup the witness table. See exactly what calls `Iterator.next` is going to make [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4255a670c43a1350c663786953e8f509d5718a96/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L125).

If you are in debug mode, none of that is going to be optimised.

Compare that to your while loop, which is basically set something to 0, compare, do the thing in the loop, add 1 to it, repeat. Clearly this is much simpler to do than calling all those methods.

If you enable optimisations however, the compiler can see that the for loop is doing what the while loop does anyway.

---

Because I find it interesting, I did a little time profile of a loop such as:

```
var s = ""
for i in 0...10000000 {
    s += "\(i)"
}
```

[image]

80% of the time is spent on `next()`, and look at how many things it does! My screenshot can't even contain everything. The string concatenating only takes up about 6% (not in the screenshot).

Comment: Thanks to you, I now could learn makeIterator() even very important concept of virtual method you talk. Thank you so much!

Comment: @HyunSu I did a time profile for a simple loop. You can see exactly how much time is spent on dispatching the protocol methods. Look at the rows that say "protocol witness ..."

Comment: Oh my god! I didn't know that cool time profiler. I should learn that. Thank you. I really want to see that. It will be very useful for me! Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Would be interesting to see the difference when we compile with optimisation. Ideally, there would be none.

Comment: You may also find it useful to run `swiftc -emit-sil -O <file.swift>`. This dumps out what Swift is "really" doing, at least at the level of the Swift Intermediate Language. Clang will generally optimize these things even further, but learning to read SIL output is a great skill for learning optimization. You may also be interested in exploring the even more massive difference in `(0..<10000000).reduce(0, +)` in non-optimized vs optimized.

Comment: @RobNapier Oh, Thank you!! Actually I knew SIL, but thanks to you, people who didn't know that concept could understand "what is SIL?, why is SIL useful in compile time? " even you give some example interesting.  Thank you so much!  I will have to learn SIL more.

Comment: @RobNapier I was using godbolt to compare the assembly code. I saw the optimised version got rid of all the `IndexingIterator`s, but otherwise couldn’t read the asm. I never knew SIL was a thing! Thank you for telling me about that too!

Comment: I love godbolt so much. It gives a lot of insight into what's going on. Compare the `-O` version of the for-loop (https://godbolt.org/z/drETfhM7j) with the `-Ounchecked` version (https://godbolt.org/z/d4T7Yd5nc). The entire loop is precomputed and turned into a single `movabs  r14, 49999995000000` (i.e. "just store the answer"). But in `-O` mode, it adds checks after every at every step for an overflow. (You can also fix that by using &+ instead of +.)

Comment: @Sweeper Hi, my professor, Could you give me information about my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032783/why-is-indexingiterator-next-using-dynamic-dispatch