# Why is indexingIterator.next() using dynamic dispatch?

Tags: swift, for-loop, compilation, iterator, dynamic-dispatch

[Why is for-in slower than while in swift debugging mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021110/why-is-for-in-slower-than-while-in-swift-debugging-mode#67021977)
I wrote this.
Thanks for people who answer to me,  I could have learned `Seqeunce` and `IteratorProtocol`.

So I implemented custom type ( `School` below code  )  which conformed `Sequence`.
And I checked Xcode-time profile.

But I can't find anything **protocol witness**
[image]

But If only use `range` and `for-in` , time profiler show  **protocol witness**.

[image]

why is `indexingIterator.next()` using **dynamic method** but not in `School` ?
I thought that even `struct` conformed `protocol`, if variable in `struct` type use method of `protocol`, this method will be **static method**.  If I am wrong, Could you please tell me what is wrong?

⬇️`School` code

```swift
struct SchoolIterator: IteratorProtocol {
    
    private var schoolList: School
    var idx = 0
    init(_ school: School) {
        self.schoolList = school
    }
    
    mutating  func next() -> String? {
        defer { idx += 1 }
        guard schoolList.count-1 >= idx
            else { return nil }
        
        return schoolList[idx]
    }
}

struct School: Sequence {
    fileprivate var list = Array(repeating: "school", count: 100000)
    var count: Int { return list.count }
    
    subscript(_ idx: Int ) -> String? {
        guard idx <= count-1
            else { return nil }
        return list[idx]
    }
    func makeIterator() -> SchoolIterator {
        return SchoolIterator(self)
    }
}
var schools = School()
for school in schools {
    print(school)
}
```

Comment: Oops, you found a mistake in my wording. `IndexingIterator.next` is not dynamically dispatched - the methods that `IndexingIterator.next` calls, such as `Collection.formIndex`, _are_. That's why you don't see a protocol witness for `next`, only ones for `formIndex`, `subscript` etc.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you so much!  I now could understand what is problem. Even today is weekend,  you answered to me.  I really appreciate with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop translates to:

```
var schools = School()
var iterator = schools.makeIterator()
while let school = iterator.next() {
    print(school)
}
```

Notice how nothing here is a protocol. `schools` is of type `School`, `iterator` is of type `SchoolIterator`, everything that `next` does (like accessing `schoolList.count`, or the subscript of `schoolList`) deals with structs too. The key point is that the compiler can figure out exactly which member you mean, because its (compile-time) type is a struct. There is no need to look up witness tables.

Compare that to, e.g.

```
func f<S: Sequence>(_ s: S) {
    for thing in s {
        ...
    }
/*
    var iterator: S.Iterator = s.makeIterator()
    while let thing = iterator.next() {
        ...
    }
*/
}

f(School())
f(1..<100)
```

How would the compiler dispatch the calls to `iterator.next()`? I've deliberately added the type annotation to make it clear what's happening - this time, the compiler doesn't know which `next` you mean. Is it `IndexingIterator.next()`? Or `SchoolIterator.next()`? Or `SomeOtherIterator.next()`? Keep in mind that I can call `f` with any kind of `Sequence`! That's why it needs to look up the witness table of the actual type of `S.Iterator` *at runtime* - it is impossible to figure out which `next` to call.

As for why `for i in 0..<100` uses dynamic dispatch, well, on first sight, there seems to be all structs:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 0..<100
var iterator: IndexingIterator<Range<Int>> = range.makeIterator()
while let i = iterator.next() {
    ...
}
```

However, `iterator.next` actually does something like [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4255a670c43a1350c663786953e8f509d5718a96/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L125):

public mutating func next() -> Elements.Element? {
if _position == _elements.endIndex { return nil }
let element = _elements[_position]
_elements.formIndex(after: &_position)
return element
}

`_elements` is defined like this:

```
public struct IndexingIterator<Elements: Collection> {
  
  internal let _elements: Elements
```

`_elements` could be any kind of `Collection`, so again, we don't know which member `_elements[_position]` or `_elements.formIndex` refers to at compile time. Is it `Array.formIndex`? Or `Set.formIndex`? We only know at runtime, when we know what `Elements` is.

Recommended reading: https://medium.com/@venki0119/method-dispatch-in-swift-effects-of-it-on-performance-b5f120e497d3

Comment: oh,  I now read your comment after reading your answer.  Okay! `iterator`is **static method**! Right?  and actually caused **dynamic method** was `_elements`!   Yeah! I now could really understand! thank you so much!! I really am happy to understand that thanks for you.  Yeah. time profile showed actually that "`Collection.formIndex`, `Collection.subscript` are **protocol witness** "  I didn't careful care about that.  Thank you so much. I really appreciate with you my professor. 

Comment: @HyunSu “statically dispatched” and “dynamically dispatched”, not “static method” and “dynamic method”. Static methods are something totally different and `dynamic` methods are message dispatched... Be careful with terminology :)

Comment: oops!  I was so happy that mistake. thank you for correcting my mistake. 

Comment: Hi, my professor, Would you mind If I ask you to answer my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67124937/11191573)?