# Can struct type be static dispatch in swift?

Tags: swift, dynamic-dispatch, static-dispatch

I think that I almost understand what will be static or dynamic dispatch.

As far as I know, **struct instance** with **struct type** will be always **static dispatch**.

```swift
struct A {
    func yo() {
        print("A")
    }
}

var a: A = A()
a.yo()
```

But, **struct instance** with **protocol type** (using protocol method) will be **dynamic dispatch** without using **protocol & extension**.

```swift
protocol Foo {
    func yo()
}

struct A: Foo {
    func yo() {
        print("A")
    }
}

var a: Foo = A()
a.yo()
```

So, I just wonder that *"Can **struct type**  be **dynamic dispatch**?"* If will, Could you tell me some example?
⬇️ **??** is anything instance

```swift
var a: structType = ?? 
a.yo()
```

Comment: Can you use some code to illustrate what you mean by "struct instance with protocol type (using protocol method) will be dynamic dispatch without using protocol & extension" and "struct type with struct instance"?

Comment: @Sweeper Okay! I edited 

Comment: Doesn't the second line answer the question? "struct instance with struct type will be always static dispatch." That said, method dispatch is a rather niche topic, so I don't think there's many people interested.

Comment: @Sweeper oh, okay, It looks I answer this question. I would want to change question like that "Can **struct type** be **dynamic dispatch**?".  I think **struct type** will be always **static dispatch**. but I don't have confidence.

Comment: I don’t know if there are any special cases (pretty sure there isn’t, but I can’t find any documentation saying that there is/isn’t). Anyway, you can start a bounty if you want to get attention to this question.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you so much.  I need just confidence by more professional developer like you.  Although you and I may have distinct time difference, you always quickly answer to me anytime. I really appreciate with you. 

Comment: "struct instance with protocol type (using protocol method) will be dynamic dispatch" No it won't.

Comment: @matt Could you tell me some example that why it doesn't ?

Comment: It just doesn’t. The dispatch is decided at compile time.

Comment: @Sweeper Hi, Would you mind if I ask you new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192198/when-to-use-dynamic-linking-library-in-ios-and-what-is-advantage-of-using-dyna) ?